# Removing empty category when using seaborn.catplot

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

I have a data frame which is described as below:

```
     dataset   method     score      input_shape
0  A dataset   method1    0.9        K=64
0  A dataset   method2    0.9        K=64
0  A dataset   method1    0.9        K=32
0  A dataset   method2    0.9        K=32
0  A dataset   method3    0.9        L=1000
0  A dataset   method3    0.9        L=2000
0  B dataset   method1    0.9        K=64
0  B dataset   method2    0.9        K=64
0  B dataset   method1    0.9        K=32
0  B dataset   method2    0.9        K=32
0  B dataset   method3    0.9        L=1000
0  B dataset   method3    0.9        L=2000
```

I am trying to use `seaborn.catplot()` to plot this datagram, to compare with performances under different dataset, and method, and input shape. Below is my code and the result I got:

```py
sns.catplot(x='method', y='score', col="dataset", \
            data=df, kind="bar",hue='input_shape', \
            palette='Set2', height=5, aspect=1)
```

[image: catplot result]

I observed that these bars are not centering with x-label due to some of my hue class is empty, but this result is not what I want. **Is there any way to remove these empty class on the plot, making these bars can center with x-label (even without using `catplot()`)?**

Any suggestion is welcomed.